# How to detect if the mouse cursor is over a pictureBox or not?

Tags: c#, winforms

```
private void pictureBox2_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            int X = e.X;
            int Y = e.Y;

            if ((X >= pictureBox2.Left && X <= pictureBox2.Left + pictureBox2.Width) && (Y >= pictureBox2.Top && Y <= pictureBox2.Top + pictureBox2.Height))
            {
                Text = "Mouse over picturebox";
            }
            else
            {
                Text = "Mouse is not over picturebox";
            }
        }
```

Sometimes it's writing to the Text that's it's not over but then when moving the mouse back inside the pictureBox2 area it's not changing the text.

mousemove full code :

```
private void pictureBox2_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            int X = e.X;
            int Y = e.Y;

            if ((X >= 0 && X <= pictureBox2.Width) && (Y >= 0 && Y <= pictureBox2.Height))
            {
                if (e.Button != MouseButtons.Left) return;

                if (pictureBox2.Image != null && selectedPath != null)
                {
                    var dr = DrawingRects[DrawingRects.Count - 1];
                    if (e.Y < dr.StartPosition.Y) { dr.Location = new Point(dr.Rect.Location.X, e.Y); }
                    if (e.X < dr.StartPosition.X) { dr.Location = new Point(e.X, dr.Rect.Location.Y); }

                    dr.Size = new Size(Math.Abs(dr.StartPosition.X - e.X), Math.Abs(dr.StartPosition.Y - e.Y));
                    pictureBox2.Invalidate();
                }
            }
        }
```

All the mouse events :

```
private void pictureBox2_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Button != MouseButtons.Left) return;

            if (pictureBox2.Image != null && selectedPath != null)
            {
                DrawingRects.Add(new DrawingRectangle()
                {
                    Location = e.Location,
                    Size = Size.Empty,
                    StartPosition = e.Location,
                    Owner = (Control)sender,
                    DrawingcColor = SelectedColor // <= Shape's Border Color
                });
            }
        }

        private void pictureBox2_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            int X = e.X;
            int Y = e.Y;

            if ((X >= 0 && X <= pictureBox2.Width) && (Y >= 0 && Y <= pictureBox2.Height))
            {
                if (e.Button != MouseButtons.Left) return;

                if (pictureBox2.Image != null && selectedPath != null)
                {
                    var dr = DrawingRects[DrawingRects.Count - 1];
                    if (e.Y < dr.StartPosition.Y) { dr.Location = new Point(dr.Rect.Location.X, e.Y); }
                    if (e.X < dr.StartPosition.X) { dr.Location = new Point(e.X, dr.Rect.Location.Y); }

                    dr.Size = new Size(Math.Abs(dr.StartPosition.X - e.X), Math.Abs(dr.StartPosition.Y - e.Y));
                    pictureBox2.Invalidate();
                }
            }
        }

        private void pictureBox2_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Button != MouseButtons.Left) return;

            if (DrawingRects.Count > 0 && pictureBox2.Image != null && selectedPath != null)
            {
                // The last drawn shape
                var dr = DrawingRects.Last();
                if (dr.Rect.Width > 0 && dr.Rect.Height > 0)
                {
                    rectImage = cropAtRect((Bitmap)pictureBox2.Image, dr.Rect);
                    if (saveRectangles)
                    {


                        rectangleName = GetNextName(Path.Combine(selectedPath, "Rectangle"), ".bmp");
                        FileList.Add($"{dr.Location}, {dr.Size}", rectangleName);
                        string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(
    FileList,
    Formatting.Indented // this for pretty print
);
                        using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(Path.Combine(selectedPath, "rectangles.txt"), false))
                        {
                            sw.Write(json);
                            sw.Close();
                        }

                        rectImage.Save(rectangleName);
                        saveRectanglesCounter++;
                    }
                    pixelsCounter = rect.Width * rect.Height;
                    
                    pictureBox1.Invalidate();

                    listBox1.DataSource = FileList.ToList();
                    listBox1.SelectedIndex = listBox1.Items.Count - 1;

                    pictureBox2.Focus();
                    Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(this.pictureBox1.Image);
                    g.Clear(this.pictureBox1.BackColor);

                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Look at Rectangle.Contains ! Also note the the y-coordinate is going from 0  __down__. Which is why your code fails..

Comment: You know there's a `Right` property, so adding `Left` and `Width` is unnecessary. There's also a `Bottom` property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `e.X` and `e.Y` properties are relative to the control raising the event, while the `Left` and `Top` of the `PictureBox` are relative to the form. If you were going to do things the way you are, this:

```cs
if ((X >= pictureBox2.Left && X <= pictureBox2.Left + pictureBox2.Width) && (Y >= pictureBox2.Top && Y <= pictureBox2.Top + pictureBox2.Height))
```

should actually be this:

```cs
if ((X >= 0 && X <= pictureBox2.Width) && (Y >= 0 && Y <= pictureBox2.Height))
```

You wouldn't do it that way though. If the `PictureBox` is raising a `MouseMove` then you're guaranteed that the mouse pointer is over the `PictureBox`, so no check is necessary or worthwhile.

Comment: @RojerBrief, you appear to have asked a question, accepted an answer that answers the question you asked, then edited your question to ask something different. DO NOT do that. The question you asked was answered. If you now have a different question, post a new question, with ALL and ONLY the information relevant to that question.